# Сборка самостоятельной ос на COSMOS

Tags: c#

Я решил попробовать поиграться с C# COSMOS, и установил COSMOS Userkit, однако при попытке сделать Release build получаю ошибку о том что COSMOS работает только в режиме Debug:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, Debug версия нуждаеться в подключении дебагера для запуска OS:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли как то запустить систему без подключения отладчика?

Comment: Никакая дебаг версия не нуждается в подключении дебаггера.

Comment: я обновил свой вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста заново

Comment: А подключиться отладчиком что именно мешает? Это же даст вам возможность ловить ошибки в своём коде. Возможно где-то в настройках это ожидание управляется.

Comment: Для разработки - подключение отладчика очень полезная вещь, однако если мне нужен полноценный релиз (а его я сделать не могу ибо космос не потдерживает версию релиза) без всякой отладки и тп, то эта отладка мне там к черту не здалась

Comment: Я тоже думаю что где то в настройках это ожидание должно управляться, однако ни в документации, ни в настройках ничего подобного не нашёл

Comment: https://github.com/CosmosOS/Cosmos/issues/1096 почитайте там комментарии

Comment: У меня и так был выключен Remote Debuging https://prnt.sc/-5LsApzEbBNP , однако Экран с ожиданием подключения дебагера всеравно присутствует

Comment: Быть может версия самого космоса старая и там баги? Убедитесь, что у вас последняя.

Comment: Вчера скачал самую новую версию

Comment: А в студии есть же какие то хоткеи для запуска без отладчика, типа там шифт+ф5 или типа того?

Comment: Сам скомпилированный проект без отладки не будет работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я спонтанно нашёл решение своей проблемы, в настройках проекта в Profile в параметре Laucnh нужно сменить ISO на VMWare(Даже если у вас другая виртуальная машина) в теории там по умолчанию должна стоять VMWare но у меня почему то стоял ISO, а затем в вкладке Debug выключить Remote Debuging